# Script Google Sheets para obtener enlace para modificar respuestas enviadas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Estoy intentando copiar este código procedente de otro [post](https://gist.github.com/rubenrivera/4ed2110cda3fbdbc29d2d2d3a4af29c0) para poder crear enlaces en una columna de Google Sheets que editen las respuestas provenientes del en envío de formularios de Google Forms.

El caso es que no me funciona el script y me da el siguiente error y no sé porqué.

> TypeError: No se puede llamar al método "getRange" de null. at getEditResponseUrls(Código:20)

Qué debería cambiar? Lo pregunto desde la más absoluto igorancia. Muchas gracias

```
/*
 * Global Variables
 */

// Form URL
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/form-id/viewform';
// Sheet name used as destination of the form responses
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
/*
 * Name of the column to be used to hold the response edit URLs 
 * It should match exactly the header of the related column, 
 * otherwise it will do nothing.
 */
var columnName = 'Edit Url' ;
// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La línea siguiente especifica el nombre de la hoja a utilizar

```
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
```

En la línea siguiente se usa el valor anterior para obtener un objeto de la clase "Sheet"

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
```

Pero como en tu hoja de cálculo no existe una hoja con el nombre `Form Responses 1`, se asigna `null` a la variable `sheet`.

Puedes corregir el error de dos formas

1. Cambia `Form Responses 1` por el nombre de la hoja vinculada al formulario de Google, **ó**
2. Cambia el nombre de la hoja vinculada al formulario de Google por `Form Responses 1`

Comment: Genial Rubén, he sincronizado los sheetNames y luego he cambiado la formURL de /viewform a /edit.

Comment: @jaime Por García revisa [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien reaponde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)